# Auto Deauthorize from a system by RingCentral

Tags: ringcentral

I have RingCentral Desktop app installed on my system which I need to Deauthorize from my system.
If I uninstall the application, will it automatically Deauthorize it from the system?
If not, what is the manual process in doing so? Also if there an API available for the process to Deauthorize the application which I can use?
I tried searching and finding the answers, I couldn't get the answers

Answer (score 0):

No there is no automated way of De-authorizing the application from the system.
All you need to do manually by going into application's `Setting --> Phone and number` section.
Here is full way of doing :
https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/4219?language=en_US

Also there is no RingCentral API available currently for the process